# Unable to write back to redshift using r from tableau

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a requirement of using r code and writing back values of tableau parameters to database. I am using below code for this purpose.

Given code works perfectly fine on R, however, tableau throws popup of start time to run the table calculation and never ends(waited for 10 mins max).

Below is my code, please suggest what is causing issue and how this can be resolved.

```
SCRIPT_INT("

install.packages('RJDBC');

library(RJDBC);

driver <- JDBC('com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver', 'RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar', identifier.quote='`');

url <- 'jdbc:redshift://aws-a0036-use1-1b-d-red-shrd-chb-dev01.cnnhjxs6xgos.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/test?user=test&password=test';

conn <- dbConnect(driver, url);

dbSendQuery(conn, 'insert into test.r_test values(.arg1);')

",

MAX([R Param]))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the Tableau connection to redshift, instead of trying to do it inside R?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Per my understanding, I will only be able to read values from redshift to tableau. Pls suggest about how redshift connection be used to write back to database also. Thanks

Comment: I've never tried to do that. Check to make sure your tableau connection has permission to insert rows to the table.  If you don't get an answer here, I'd try calling customer support.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I tried to use the custom sql option in tableau but that works only to get data, giving error while writing insert command in that

Comment: How many rows do you have in the underlying data source where you've created this calculated field? The function will run for every single source row so depending on the size, it may take a while because R has to open a db connection and insert a new row for each data source row.

Comment: @SamM data is huge where I have created this calcualted field. However, number of rows are very less in the table where we need to write the values